# What is the way to make the tool-tip box visible as you scroll through the overflow area?

Tags: javascript, html, css

As you can see, the tooltip is covered and it's not showing properly.

How can I make the tooltip box look clear and scroll when the contents in the fixed area overflow and make the scrolling variable and when the tool chip box made with "Positive:Absolute" is incorrect? The layout I want is shown below.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: lavender;
}

.test1 {
  width: 300px;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);
  background-color: pink;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  position: relative;
}

.contents1,
.contents3 {
  width: 230px;
  margin: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.contents2,
.contents4 {
  width: 144px;
  position: relative;
}

.tooltip {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 3px;
  right: 3px;
  background-color: red;
}

.tooltip-contents {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: black;
  position: absolute;
  left: calc(100% + 20px);
  top: -5px;
  color: #fff;
  word-break: break-all
}
```

```html
<div class="containter">
  <div class="header"></div>
  <div>
    <div class="test1">
      <div class="contents1">
        <p>contents header</p>
        <div class="contents2">
          <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150" />
          <div class="tooltip">
            <span class="tooltip-icon"></span>
            <div class="tooltip-contents">
              abcdefgdfsafdasdfsadfsadfasdfsadf
            </div>
            <div>
              <div></div>
            </div>
            <div class="test2"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

- jQuery is not available. Only minimal JavaScript is possible.

[this layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lSDpu.png)

Comment: Do you want to use `tooltip` inside the scroll bar, hover over the scroll bar and follow the scrolling elements inside

Comment: Each content has an icon, and tooltips are based on that icon. I don't know what to do.

Comment: Do you write `tooltip` yourself or use a plugin, I don't recommend writing it myself. The 'DOM' of 'tooltip' written inside the scroll bar cannot exceed the scroll bar. If you want to exceed it, you need to write it outside, so you need to listen for the 'DOM' position change and modify the prompt position.

Answer (score 0):

It is important that `data-container='body'`so that the tooltip can be displayed outside the scrollbar.

```css
.scroll-wrap {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  overflow: auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 3px orange;
}
.scroll-wrap button {
  margin-top:30px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.staticfile.org/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 <script src="https://cdn.staticfile.org/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.staticfile.org/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
  <div class="scroll-wrap">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" data-html="true" title="<div style='color: red'>div demo</div>">Right Tooltip
  </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Right Tooltip">Right Tooltip
  </button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Right Tooltip">Right Tooltip
  </button>
  </div>

<script>
$(function () { 
  $("[data-toggle='tooltip']").tooltip(); 
  });
</script>
```

This supports `HTML` fragments

Comment: "Title" may not be available. The tool-tip consists of 'div'. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: @aria1220 This supports `HTML` code snippet, The above code has been updated